# Cannot make mysql database connection from php

Tags: linux, nginx, mysql

I am not being able to make database connection from php. I'm getting HTTP 500 Internal Server Error while making database connection.
My PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "shudarsan";
$password = "shudarsan@localhost";
$database = "userInfo";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if(!$conn) {
    echo("Failed to connect to the database");
}else {
    echo "Connection to the database was successfully made";
}
echo "hello there";
?>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox2F1.png

/var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
thrown in /var/www/php/projects/loginsys/partials/_dbConnect.php on line 6" while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: php, request: "GET /projects/loginsys/partials/_dbConnect.php HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "php"
```

I am able to make mysql database connection from console (i.e. `mysql -u root -p`) and mysql user i.e. shudarsan has all privileges on the database. All the database info in the php files are correct. When I run the php code, I get HTTP 500 Internal Server Error message on the webpage.

Comment: Is it only this php file or every php file that doesn't work? I don't think it is a problem with your code or your database, rather with the configuration of PHP and nginx. Please provide your nginx configuration for that server.

Comment: You have a speical charachter @ in the password and may be that is causing the problem. Try using single quote 'shudarsan@localhost' and see if it works.

Comment: It is the only php file

Comment: @ in the password might not be creating problem because earlier, i was trying to make connection from root user. and the password of the root user didn't have any special character.

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php to get the exact error message from MySQL.